# java.lang.NullPointerException PrintWriter

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, try-catch, printwriter

I am getting a NullPointerException when I run my code. I have narrowed down the problem to line 38: when it is commented out the program doesn't give any errors. I just have "test" here for now.

```
out.println("test")
```

The run method is immediately started with the following two lines in another class

```
Client test = new Client();
test.start();
```

And when a button is pressed the following code is executed which runs the sendToServer method

```
Client test = new Client();
test.sendToServer(cipherText)
```

Below is the full code for my Client class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client extends Thread{

    String line = "";
    String cipherText = "";

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;

    public void run(){
            String serverAddress = "00.000.000.000";
        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 8888);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true) {
            try{
                line = in.readLine();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        } 
    }

    public void sendToServer(String in) {
        out.println("test");
    }

}
```

Thanks for looking, I am still learning java so excuse any obvious mistakes.

Comment: You'll have to establish a connection to the server - the socket must be well-established - before you can read and write on the streams bound to the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have used `PrintWriter out;` as your class member but you have not initialized it. By default, all un-initialized member objects are initialized with `null`. If `sendToServer()` is called first, `out` will be `null` and you will get `NullPointerException`.

**EDIT**

Problem is that you are trying to invoke `run()` and `sendToServer()` methods on two separate instances of `Client`.

```
Client test = new Client(); // First instance
test.start();               // which calls run() and then initializes out variable.
```

Then a second instance is created from:

```
Client test = new Client();    // Second instance
test.sendToServer(cipherText); // since out is not initialized for this instance, you are getting NPE
```

I suppose you are using `Client` object in a multi-threaded environment, in that case I would suggest you to make sure that both threads are using same instance of `Client` object. Also if `Client` instance is being shared, you might want to make access to `out` variable synchronized and also make sure that `Client`'s run method is executed first before button is pressed (which in turn calls `sendToServer()`).

Comment: i have used `test.start();` to call `run();` which i can confirm is communicating  with my server program before i call sendToServer. You can see this in the second code snipet i gave in my initial question.

Comment: Ah, okay, so the problem is that you are invoking `sendToServer()` and `run()` method on two separate instances of `Client`.

Comment: I altered my code slightly slight and can confirm that the issue is that they were both running on two separate instances. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You have in the beggining of the class:

```
PrintWriter out;
```

if you don't call run() [is where you initialize it] before sendToServer(), "out" would never be initialized and will be null.

Comment: Dose the second code snipet i showcased not start run()?

Answer (score 0):

```
Your function assumes out Printwriter will be initialized, but if there is an exception in the socket initialization, it will never by initialized.  Two things I would do...

1. Initialize out to null at the top of the run method.

2. protect your sendToServer code...

public void sendToServer(String in) throws NullPointerException
{
    if (out == null)
    {
          throw new NullPointerException("Out is null.");
    }
    out.println("test");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have implemented this and can confirm that out is not being initialized.

Comment: user987339 has identified the root of the problem... your server address is zeroes.  For simple testing, the loop back address of "127.0.0.1" is a good idea.

Comment: The server address is not the problem, it was working with my public address which i have chosen to not share. when the correct address is added my server program acknowledges the connection.